# Django anon cart system not working on first visit to site

Tags: javascript, python, django, cookies

I wanted to implement an anonymous cart system to my django site. I saw on internet that I can achieve with the following javascript code:

```
function getCookie(name) {
    let cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
        const cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
        for (let i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
            const cookie = cookies[i].trim();
            // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
            if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return cookieValue;
}
const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

function uuidv4() {
  return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
    var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
    return v.toString(16);
  });
}


let device = getCookie('device')

if (device == null || device == undefined){
    device = uuidv4()
}

document.cookie ='device=' + device + ";domain=;path=/"
```

Which is embedded at the end of 'base.html' which is a template every other html uses. like this: `<script src="{% static 'js/cookies.js'%}"></script>`

Followed by this home page code:

```
class HomeView(ListView):
    template_name = "index.html"

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = get_base_lists(self.request)
        ...
        return render(self.request, self.template_name, context)

...

def get_base_lists(request):
   ...
   cart, created = Order.objects.get_or_create(
            user=auth_status(request),
            device=auth_status(request, False)
        )
   # Order is created in such a way that user or device can be null, but not at the same time.
   ...
   return {'cart': cart }

...

def auth_status(request, for_user: bool = True):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return None if for_user is False else request.user
    else:
        device_name = request.COOKIES['device']

        device_obj, created = Device.objects.get_or_create(
            name=device_name
        )

        return None if for_user is True else device_obj
```

This originally worked on my development pc (Widnows), however I wanted to test my site on another pc (Linux/Debian) but ran into an error saying:

```
KeyError at /
'device'
at line device_name = request.COOKIES['device']
```

Upon further inspection I realized maybe this happens because, in HomeView I try to access `device` before the javascript is ran and device is thus set.

In homeView, I try to access it in `context = get_base_lists(self.request)` line, but `device` is set in the return statement, which sends the html to the user, causing the javascript to run and set the device.

How can I get around this? Is there a better way to implement anonymous cart system?

OS: Debian
Python version: 3.9.2
Django version: 4.0.4

Answer (score 1):

I found a couple of small issues related to the codes you shared here.

1. The code you provided appears to be mostly correct, but there's a small issue with the document.cookie line. The extra double quotation marks at the end of the line may be causing the issue. Here's the corrected line:

`document.cookie = 'device=' + device + '; domain=; path=/';`

2. When setting the domain attribute for the cookie, you should specify the domain where your Django site is hosted. If you want the cookie to be accessible across all subdomains, you can set it to the root domain like this.

`document.cookie = 'device=' + device + '; domain=.yourdomain.com; path=/';`

Modify these first and see what happens.

Add this code to your views.py.

```
def auth_status(request, for_user: bool = True):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return None if for_user is False else request.user
    else:
        device_name = request.COOKIES.get('device')  # Use get() to avoid KeyError

        if device_name is not None:
            device_obj, created = Device.objects.get_or_create(
                name=device_name
            )

            return None if for_user is True else device_obj
        else:
            # Handle the case when 'device' cookie is not present
            return None  # or raise an exception, depending on your requirements
```

Comment: the code you provided seems good, but the problem is that the javascript is not ran, at all. For javascript to run, the view request should successfuly return, but it cannot because it should run the javascript for the device to work....

Comment: What's the detailed error? Can you share the relevant logs here?

Comment: `views.py", line 35, in auth_status
    device_name = request.COOKIES['device']
KeyError: 'device'`

That's it.

Comment: views.py? What is it? Can you copy the code in line 35?

Comment: It's provided above, on `auth_status` function.

Comment: I have added exception handing to solve the "Key Error". Let's solve this problem first.

Comment: The problem with that solution is the fact that under that line, there is a device_obj creation which requires either a user or a device, so when one of them is null it gives another error saying both can't be null.

Comment: You can raise an exception, depending on your requirements, Null is not necessary.